# chart inline image cropped

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-visualization

I am trying to put a chart created in google sheets into a gmail html body as an inline image. It appears, but it gets cropped (image left), and I can't figure out how to show the whole chart. The chart appears whole and OK in the sheet (image right)

[cropped chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wJKI.png)      [uncropped chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc0bK.png)

Here is the code:

```
//creates chart of tasks to embed an inline image in gmail message
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
     .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.TABLE)
     .addRange(range)
     .setOption('height', 800)
     .setPosition(1,1,0,0)
     .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);

  var table = sheet.getCharts()[0];

  var htmlList = '<h2>Tasks:</h2><img src="cid:chart1" />';
      htmlList = htmlList + '<br><br>Click <a href="https://sites.google.com/a/dwightlondon.org/dsl-whole-school-staff-hub/new-students" target="_blank">here</a> to visit Induction page';

table.modify().setOption('height', 800)
  var taskList = table.getAs('image/gif').setName('chart1');



  GmailApp.sendEmail('adadasd@dwightlondon.org', 
                     'Updated induction tasks for '+userType + ' ' + student, 
                     'tasks: ',
                     { htmlBody: htmlList, 
                       inlineImages: {
                          chart1: taskList
                        }});

  sheet.removeChart(table[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the image is being cropped as result of the default size values.

With the embedded charts I was not able to change the size, however, I tried using the [Charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/table-chart-builder) service and was able to set the dimensions.

So modifying your code a little bit I got the complete Chart:

```
var chart = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(range.getDataTable()).setDimensions(600, 600).build();

var htmlList = '<h2>Tasks:</h2><img src="cid:chart1" />';
      htmlList = htmlList + '<br><br>Click <a href="https://sites.google.com/a/dwightlondon.org/dsl-whole-school-staff-hub/new-students" target="_blank">here</a> to visit Induction page';

  GmailApp.sendEmail('adadasd@dwightlondon.org', 
                     'Updated induction tasks for '+userType + ' ' + student, 
                     'tasks: ',
                     { htmlBody: htmlList, 
                       inlineImages: {
                          chart1: chart.getBlob().setName('chart1')
                        }});
```

Check if this works for you.